# Does the pthreads functions set the errno internally?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

In the below code i am calling pthread_join() with thread id as self. Result is that it returns error number 35. So same i am trying to print with perror. But it is displaying "success". My doubt is does library/system calls need to explictly set the errno for any errors or Did i miss any thing ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define DEATH(mess) { perror(mess); exit(errno); }

static void * threadFunc(void *arg)
{
 void *res;
 printf("sleeping for 2 sec ...\n");
 sleep(2);
 char *s = (char *) arg;
 pthread_t t = pthread_self();
 int relval = pthread_join(t, &res);

 if (relval) 
  perror("deadlock");

  printf("return value is %d .....\n",relval);
  return (void *) strlen(s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 pthread_t t1;
 void *res;
 int ret;

 ret = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threadFunc, "Hello world\n");
 if (ret != 0)
    DEATH ("pthread_create");

 printf("Message from main()\n");

 pthread_exit(&res);
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

```
o/p

Message from main()
sleeping for 2 sec ...
deadlock: Success
return value is 35 .....
```

Comment: Why don't you read the man page?

Comment: That's not a doubt, it's a question.

Answer (score 7):

There is no requirement that thesr functions set `errno` or that they leave it alone. You're always free to do:

```
errno = pthread_join(t, &res);
```

Comment: Thanks -- this made me realize I can also use this with `perror`, since (on my system) all the codes `pthread_join` and `pthread_create` might return are standard ones understood by `perror` -- `EAGAIN`, `ESRCH`, etc.

(Based on the man page on OS X 10.11.3, El Capitan.)  I don't know if this is part of the pthreads standard, though.

Answer (score 3):

pthread_join() does not set the errno value

Please refer to the discussion here:

[pthread: join a detached thread doesn't set errno correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917944/pthread-join-a-detached-thread-doesnt-set-errno-correctly)

Your best bet is to just use the return value of pthread_join

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.

1. You should not be doing a join from within the thread itself. The join is supposed to be done from the parent thread, to clean up the resources there.
2. The errno variable is a per thread variable. It's value will be different when you access it within the thread, and in main.

Comment: Also note that there's no reliable way you can cause `pthread_join` to return an error. The only possible errors it could return involve situations where you have invoked undefined behavior such as using a thread ID after its lifetime has ended.