# Pthreads - Can I detach from a thread and then join in main?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, pthread-join

What I want to do is something on lines of...

```
pthread_create(&producer_thread, &to_join, producer_routine, &queue);
pthread_detach(producer_thread);
...
...
pthread_join(producer_thread, NULL);
```

Is this possible in some way, on running the above code, it is unable to join the thread.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: No.  Detaching a thread makes it permanently un-joinable.  If you are in control of the thread function, however, then you can roll your own mechanism for waiting on specific detached threads.

Comment: Always a good idea to read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html): "Once a thread has been detached, it can't be joined with pthread_join(3) or be made joinable again."

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13917944/694576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once detached, it's not possible to join anymore.

From *Notes* on [`pthread_detach()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)'s man page:

> Once a thread has been detached, it can't be joined with
>          [`pthread_join(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) or be made joinable again.